# I need an explanation on how nth-of-type works

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code and I can't figure out why the nth-of-type selector needs to be 2, not 1, for the first sibling of this type.

Here's a jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/xj5hvn16/

Can someone, please, explain this to me?

```css
.flowbox .utm_registrars_code:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flowbox freebox">
  <div class="pholdcard18"></div>
  <div class="flowcard14 utm_registrars_code">
    <div class="content">
      Content 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flowcard14 utm_registrars_code">
    <div class="content">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flowcard14 utm_registrars_code">
    <div class="content">
      Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `nth-of-type` starts with the first element of a certain type, in your case a `div`, and not the first element with the selected class

> The :nth-of-type() pseudo-class represents an element that has an+b
>   siblings with the same expanded element name before it in the document
>   tree, for any zero or positive integer value of n, and has a parent
>   element.

More info:

- https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 1):

`nth-of-type` does not mean `nth-of-class`!

The first element of type `div` is

```
<div class="pholdcard18"></div>
```

Hence your `Content 1` element is the second and highlighted.